# Need possible options for "App wrapping " in Android

Tags: android

I want to know about the "App wrapping" options available in Android.
My requirement is to have control over the 2-3 apks, that will be wrapped together.
The apks will communicate with each other for data sharing but not with third-party apps.

Any options in Android for wrapping the apks.

Comment: sounds to me like you need to export JAR files or use library refrences

Comment: Do you mean to say, unpacking the apk to JAR files?

Comment: if all the projects are yours you can have them in the same workspace and reference them to each oter

Comment: Thats the problem here, projects are not mine. Those are ready apks for which some how I want to create rules or permissions to allow or disallow copy-paste functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decompile the app using apktool/dex2jar and then use AOP to inject code. Then you'll need to recompile the app and sign it.

Comment: What if the android app was coded with C++ (NDK) and not Java?

Answer (score 0):

[Use](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) the same certificate to sign them (no JARs, or library references needed, unless your app is already structured that way):

> **Application modularity** – The Android system allows applications that
>   are signed by the same certificate to run in the same process, if the
>   applications so requests, so that the system treats them as a single
>   application. In this way you can deploy your application in modules,
>   and users can update each of the modules independently if needed.

Then use a ContentProvider that you flag with `android:exported=false` in the manifest to make sure outside applications don't have access to it.

Comment: The problem here is that the source is not available. I will only get apks on which need to write some wrapper for controlling the copy-paste operations.

Comment: If these apks are not yours to rebuild as you wish, I'm not sure "wrapper" is the word I'd use. Can you give us more background information? Are those 2 or 3 apps on Google Play? I suppose you could make your own custom keyboard that would only work when those apps are active, or perhaps if they already have that kind of interface enabled, I suppose you could do something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grilledmonkey.ctrlc but that would work only with those apps and none others.

Comment: No apks are not on Play. The apks will be downloaded from some enterprise server. Also the custom keyboard will not help in this case, since long press on EditText will have option to copy. Somehow I want to detect the copy-paste event at system service level, then intercept the event based on the package name i.e. if my package is calling copy or paste allow the operation.

Comment: Ah ok, since it's an enterprise environment, can you provide your own custom rom? Or will you have administrative control over these devices?

Comment: Custom ROM option is not possible. But i think having the control over the devices is possible. Any pointers for having the control over the devices....may be using the DevicePolicyManager or something else?